# Python's string.translate() doesn't fully work?

Tags: python, unicode

Given this example, I get the error that follows:

```
print u'\2033'.translate({2033:u'd'})

C:\Python26\lib\encodings\cp437.pyc in encode(self, input, errors)
     10
     11     def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
---> 12         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
     13
     14     def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x83' in position 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
>>> print u'\u2033'.translate({0x2033:u'd'})
d
```

Since you used `u'\2033'` instead of `u'\u2033'`, The result was two characters: `u'\203'+u'3'`. Trying to print this gave an exception because your terminal's encoding doesn't support the character `u'\203'` (which is the same as `u'\x83'`).

Also note the difference between `2033` and `0x2033` in the dictionary: The `\uxxxx` escape sequence  takes its value in hexadecimal, so you'd need `0x2033` to match it.

Regarding your question's title, `string.translate` (the `translate` function in the `string` module) doesn't support a dictionary as a parameter, but calling `.translate` on the unicode string itself (as you did in the question body) works.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. What I don't understand is why the following solution doesn't work for 2033.

http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2854253/revisions

Comment: @Rhubarb: If you're referring to the solution using `unidecode` and `translate`, it works for me: it replaces `u"\u2033"` with `u"''"`

Comment: That's odd, can you post the exact code you've used? My copy/version of what I got from that solution returns an empty string.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I am out of my mind, it works for me as well. It seems that I interpreted '' as an empty string, when I forgot that for python interpreter shell, it will literally return no characters for empty string.